Are the residents of Vaikuntha similar in oppulance to that of Kṛṣṇa?
I found a text of Satyanarayan Das Maharaj of the Gaudiya Sampradaya where he has cited the following verse:

ete hi yādavāḥ sarve madgaṇā eva bhāmini sarvadā mat-priyā devi
mat-tulya-guṇa-śālinaḥ

Lord Kṛṣṇa said, O beautiful one, all the Yādavas are My associates. O Goddess, they are all dear to Me and they all have qualities just like My qualities.
He has mentioned it that it is mentioned by Srila Jiva Goswami in his work - Kṛṣṇa-sandarbha.
I want to understand that do the associates of Kṛṣṇa possess similar oppulances and potencies as Himself? This doubt is from the above translation - "they all have qualities just like My qualities."
How do the Gaudiya Vaishanavas and followers of Achintya Bheda-Abhed Vedanta interpret it?

i believe you mistyping spell mistake when you type achintya bheda bhed, it is achintya bheda- abheda.. abheda identifying oneness with the lord himself posses same quality and oppulence as that of lord living is mythical wordl

@PrasannaR thank you for identifying my mistake. I will correct it.

All Jivas who reach Vaikuntha as Nityasuris look like Vishnu himself:
https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/15/
Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Canto 3:

Text 13: After thus traveling all over the universes, they also entered into the spiritual sky, for they were freed from all material contamination. In the spiritual sky there are spiritual planets known as Vaikuṇṭhas, which are the residence of the Supreme Personality of Godhead and His pure devotees and are worshiped by the residents of all the material planets.


Text 14: In the Vaikuṇṭha planets all the residents are similar in form to the Supreme Personality of Godhead. They all engage in devotional service to the Lord without desires for sense gratification.


As per Achintya Bheda-Abheda, the Abheda is due to the quality of Satchidananda (Sat means eternal, cit means full of knowledge, and bliss means full of jubilation) which is inherent to both Lord Krishna as well as His associates.
The Bheda is due to the spiritual sentiment in the Vaikuntha planets which is Bhakti or intense devotion unto Krishna. Hence, the exhibition of opulences known as Aisvarya like those possessed by Lord Krishna does not take place.
Even though the associates of the spiritual realm are fully equipped with all the opulence by the grace of the Lord such as taking multiple forms, performing extraordinary activities like the lifting the Govardhan Hill, etc. they do not do so to be able to exchange the transcendental mellow of devotion with the Lord which is known as Rasa. In fact, even Krishna Himself does not manifest them in the spiritual planet known as in Goloka-Vrindavana.
In Vaikuntha, where the four-handed form of Lord Narayana is worshipped along with Lakshmi-ji, the opulences similar to the Lord can be seen to some degree in His associates, such as possessing four-handed forms, flying in Vimanas, etc.

ये यथा मां प्रपद्यन्ते तांस्तथैव भजाम्यहम् । मम वर्त्मानुवर्तन्ते
मनुष्याः पार्थ सर्वशः ॥ ११ ॥
As all surrender unto Me, I reward them accordingly. Everyone follows
My path in all respects, O son of Pṛthā.

